# RadioButtons and Buttons not doing anything in custom Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

So I created custom `xml` dialog and I want to program it like this: It has two `RadioButton`s and if one is clicked some UI elements like `TextView`s and `EditTex`ts appear, and they dissapear if the other `RadioButton` is checked.

The problem is, `Button` and `RadioButton`s are not doing anything. I've set visibility for UI elements to appear and dissapear as `RadioButton`s are checked but it's not working. Same thing with `Button`, it should pass the result in activites `EditText` but when pressed it does nothing.

I don't get any errors so please don't ask me to post logcats because app does not crash.

Here's the code of that dialog:

```
statistikeInputDialogKalkulatoriFFMI = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.statistikeInputDialogKalkulatoriFFMI);


    statistikeInputDialogKalkulatoriFFMI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(StatistikeInputMain.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_statistike_uredi_ffmi);
            dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_uredi1RM));
            dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
            dialog.show();
            RadioGroup radioGrupaDialogFFMI = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGrupaDialogFFMI);
            final RadioButton radioButtonDialogFFMIMetric = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonDialogFFMIMetric);
            final RadioButton radioButtonDialogFFMIImperial = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonDialogFFMIImperial);
            textTezinaDialogFFMI = (TextView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.textTezinaDialogFFMI);
            textBodyFatDialogFFMI = (TextView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.textBodyFatDialogFFMI);
            textVisinaDialogMetricFFMI = (TextView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.textVisinaDialogMetricFFMI);
            textVisinaDialogImperialFFMI = (TextView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.textVisinaDialogImperialFFMI);
            editTezinaDialogFFMI = (EditText)dialog. findViewById(R.id.editTezinaDialogFFMI);
            editBodyFatDialogFFMI = (EditText)dialog. findViewById(R.id.editBodyFatDialogFFMI);
            editVisinaDialogMetricFFMI = (EditText)dialog. findViewById(R.id.editVisinaDialogMetricFFMI);
            editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIFEET = (EditText)dialog. findViewById(R.id.editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIFEET);
            editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIINCH = (EditText)dialog. findViewById(R.id.editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIINCH);
            buttonDialogIzracunajFFMI = (Button)dialog. findViewById(R.id.buttonDialogIzracunajFFMI);
            editTextStatistikeFFMI = (EditText)dialog. findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeFFMI);

            textVisinaDialogMetricFFMI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textVisinaDialogImperialFFMI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editVisinaDialogMetricFFMI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIFEET.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIINCH.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.radioButtonDialogFFMIMetric:
            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

                    if (checked)

                        textTezinaDialogFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textBodyFatDialogFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textVisinaDialogMetricFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editTezinaDialogFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editBodyFatDialogFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editVisinaDialogMetricFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonDialogIzracunajFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    buttonDialogIzracunajFFMI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            double tezina = Double.parseDouble(editTezinaDialogFFMI.getText().toString());
                            double bodyfat = Double.parseDouble(editBodyFatDialogFFMI.getText().toString());
                            double visina = Double.parseDouble(editVisinaDialogMetricFFMI.getText().toString());
                            double rezultatLean = 0;
                            double rezultatFFMI = 0;

                            rezultatLean = tezina * (1.0 - (bodyfat / 100.0));
                            rezultatLean = Math.round(rezultatLean * 100.0) / 100.0;


                            rezultatFFMI = (rezultatLean / 2.2) / (((visina / 2.54) * 0.0254) * ((visina / 2.54) * 0.0254)) * 2.20462;
                            rezultatFFMI = Math.round(rezultatFFMI * 100.0) / 100.0;
                            editTextStatistikeFFMI.setText(Double.toString(rezultatFFMI));

                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

                case R.id.radioButtonDialogFFMIImperial:
                    boolean checked1 = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

                    if (checked1)

                        textTezinaDialogFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textBodyFatDialogFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textVisinaDialogImperialFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editTezinaDialogFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editBodyFatDialogFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIFEET.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIINCH.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonDialogIzracunajFFMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonDialogIzracunajFFMI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            double tezina = Double.parseDouble(editTezinaDialogFFMI.getText().toString());
                            double bodyfat = Double.parseDouble(editBodyFatDialogFFMI.getText().toString());
                            double visinaFEET = Double.parseDouble(editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIFEET.getText().toString());
                            double visinaINCH = Double.parseDouble(editVisinaDialogImperialFFMIINCH.getText().toString());
                            double rezultatLean = 0;
                            double rezultatFFMI = 0;


                            rezultatLean = tezina * (1.0 - (bodyfat / 100.0));
                            rezultatLean = Math.round(rezultatLean * 100.0) / 100.0;


                            rezultatFFMI = (rezultatLean / 2.2) / (((visinaFEET * 12.0 + visinaINCH) * 0.0254) * ((visinaFEET * 12.0 + visinaINCH) * 0.0254));
                            rezultatFFMI = Math.round(rezultatFFMI * 100.0) / 100.0;
                            editTextStatistikeFFMI.setText(Double.toString(rezultatFFMI));

                            dialog.dismiss();


                        }

                    });
            }
```

Comment: use `Clickable="true"` in your parent view inside the `dialog_statistike_uredi_ffmi.xml`

Answer (score 0):

All your hide/show + view inflation logic inside the OnClick callback which is wrong, All of that should be written within your DialogFragment class(Use DialogFragment instead of the dialog that you're using since it is the recommended way)

The logic to hide and show your UI controls as well as the clickListeners for your Button and RadioButton of the dialog should be written separately - for eg: in the OnCreate of your DialogFragment.